# Protractor - How to exclude spec file in the config file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

Suppose I have 10 spec files all are named `*********.test.js`, I want to run my tests on all 9 files except the file `Idontwantyou.test.js`.

Currently I am finding my spec files in my `config.file` with:

`specs: ['*.test.js']` - this will run all 10 files.

How do I make it run all the 9 test files but skip the `Idontwantyou.test.js`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can `exclude` the spec's by adding them in the exclude tag in you conf.js file. You can also add patterns to exclude many test scripts with similar names. Here's how to do it -

```
exclude: ['Idontwantyou.test.js'],
```

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L211). Hope this helps. If that link is broken, search the [config file](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts) for "exclude".

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that there is exclude tag!

Comment: Unfortunately, both links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

As Grish suggested you can use exclude . As per the comment of Darkbound the exact location is given below .Modify the config.js as per below .

In here  in specs: I mentioned the src/com/sam/scriptjs/ExcelTest.js but since I specifically excluded it , it won;t get picked .

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',

    multiCapabilities: [{
          'browserName': 'firefox'
        }, {
          'browserName': 'chrome'
        }],
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  exclude: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/winstonlogs.spec.js','src/com/sam/scriptjs/ExcelTest.js'],
  specs: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/nonangularstackscript.spec.js','src/com/sam/scriptjs/radiobutton.spec.js','src/com/sam/scriptjs/ExcelTest.js']


}
```